# He is "a responsible policeman and father" or "a responsible policeman and a responsible father"

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-articles

In the following sentence, is it correct to just use one 'a' before the two nouns 'policeman' and 'father'?

> He is a responsible policeman and father.

Or do I need to put it as 'He is a responsible policeman and a responsible father'?

Comment: I think both uses are correct.

Comment: It's a matter of style.

Answer (score 2):

No need to say "he is a responsible policeman and **responsible** father" -- your original construction "he is a responsible policeman and father" is good enough in this case, but you must use this construction only if the adjective 'responsible' applies to **both** the nouns,  to avoid misinterpretation by the reader.

Other examples:

She is a devoted wife **and** mother.

(She is a devoted wife and also a devoted mother.)

They are incorrigible cheats **and** liars.

(They are incorrigible cheats and also incorrigible liars.)

When the adjective does **not** apply to both nouns, but applies only to one of them, you must not use the above construction.

Example:

1. She avoids violent movies and sports.

This can mean that she avoids violent movies and **violent** sports, but if you did not mean that, but actually meant to say that she avoids 'sports in general' and also avoids 'violent movies', then you could rewrite it as

"she avoids sports and violent movies."

2. He enjoys spicy food and puzzles.

Surely this does not mean he enjoys spicy food and **spicy** puzzles?!

In fact there are some spicy puzzles. 
(Simple sample: I am in soup but not in cake -- what spice am I? Answer: pepper)

You could avoid any possible misinterpretation in such cases by separating the 2 nouns such that the adjective applies only to the proper one, as in

He likes puzzles and spicy food, or

He likes spicy food and **solving** puzzles.

Note 2: if you were to write

"he is a responsible policeman and **a father**"

then the adjective "responsible" would no longer apply to "father" which has now become separated from "policeman." Then the sentence would be understood as

"he is a father and a responsible policeman"

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! Your answer is really detailed and has cleared up my confusion!! :]

Comment: You are welcome. By the by, it's a good question!

Comment: I don't agree with some of your examples, namely: "He enjoys spicy food and puzzles." You yourself stated "surely this does not mean he enjoys spicy food and spicy puzzles?" The sentence is not at all ambiguous because it's assumed that the reader is reasonable enough to understand that there is no such thing as a "spicy puzzle" .

Comment: @AleksandrH I will agree that sentence leaves only a very slim chance of misinterpretation, but we are still required to assume that the reader is well-versed enough in English not to apply the adjective 'spicy' to 'puzzle' by mistake and get confused as a result -- I was simply advising OP to avoid *all possible chance of being misunderstood* as some teachers of English recommend. Would you say the other example 'she avoids violent movies and sports' is an equally unambiguous construction?

Comment: No, the other sentence is definitely ambiguous. And I agree that it doesn't take much effort to reword the sentences to avoid any potential ambiguity. I was just saying that for the one I quoted, ambiguity would only arise if someone doesn't know, say, what a puzzle is.

Comment: @AleksandrH I understand. The thing is that there are so many English learners who get puzzled by such things that we find so clear because we know our English!